# Alternative Zoom option on JIT Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, infovis

I am using Java Infovis Toolkit. And I want any button option for zooming rather than Mouse wheel. Can Anyone help me with how can I apply two buttons for Zoom in and Zoom out rather than mouse wheel.

Comment: I am not getting any idea how will I be able to add zoom in and zoom out button. On default mouse scroll is active for zoom in and zoom out and I am confused to add new function on jquery.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two buttons, for zooming in/out then you can use following handler functions with them.

```
handler: function(btn){
                        //zoom in
                        var val = fd.controller.Navigation.zooming/1000; 
                        var ans = 1 + (10 * val);
                        fd.canvas.scale(ans, ans);
         }
```

For zoom out,

```
handler: function(btn){
                        //zoom out
                        var val = fd.controller.Navigation.zooming/1000;  
                        var ans = 1 - (10 * val);
                        fd.canvas.scale(ans, ans);
         }
```

Here fd is the instance of ForceDirected visualization, you can replace that by an instance of your visualization.